# MySQL server-id not being set with Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, mysql, systemd

I am setting up a mysql slave on a Fedora 16 system, and the `server_id` is not being set properly. My `/etc/my.cnf` is:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=16
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
read-only = 1
symbolic-links=0
max_allowed_packet = 100000000

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

However, after `systemctl restart mysqld.service`, `show variables like "server_id"` indicates that `server_id` is `0`, which causes replication to fail.

`/var/log/mysqld.log` was last modified when I last restarted the server, but there are no log entries from then (I did the restart today, and the last entry is from yesterday).

Why doesn't `server-id=16` work? Does it need to be set in some other file? Alternatively, is there a way to edit the `systemd` unit file such that `mysqld` starts with the `--server-id=` command line option, or get `mysqld` to run an SQL statement to set the `server_id` on startup?

Comment: What is your master server id? Or do you have another mysql server using same id? They all have to be different.

Comment: The master server id is `1`. The replication works when `server_id` on the slave is not `0`; the trouble is that the slave `server_id` is reset to `0` when the slave restarts.

Comment: On your slave box, turn off and on `mysqld`, then check `/var/log/syslog`(you may not have this) or `/var/log/messages` to see if there is some error or warning messages on mysqld startup process.

Comment: There's an SELinux read error on `my.cnf`.

Comment: What is the permission on `my.cnf`? Is it 777 now? maybe change it to 660 or 644, should be own by `root`.

Comment: Additionally, where is `my.cnf` located? On Fedora, it should be '/etc/my.cnf'

Comment: On `/etc/my.cnf`, permissions `644`, `root:root`. `ls -Z` shows that it is context `user_home_t`.

Comment: In `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, try to pin point the line selinux complaint about mysqld accessing /etc/my.cnf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use check selinux contexts, they may be wrong

For `mysqld` startup, shutdown messages, other than `/var/log/mysqld.log`, also check `/var/log/messages`.

If the messages(warn/error) show `sealert` suggestion, check mysqld selinux contexts, they may be wrong or out of date. Update accordingly may fix the issue.

To use `--server-id=` in mysqld startup script, check following locations

```
/etc/sysconfig/
```

There maybe a `mysqld` file which you can customize startup option.

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/
```

`mysqld` startup script reside here. You can hard code the option in the script. But you will have to apply the changes each time your up grade.

PS: You may want to consider switching slave box OS to debian/ubuntu so system knowledge will apply to both machines. Additionally, (IMHO) Fedora is not a good choice for a production/server box due to the distro short life span (6mo shelf life + 6mo update support). If RedHat related OS is preferred, use RedHat or CentOS.

Comment: Running an `sealert` command suggested in `messages` gave the way to solve the problem, which was an incorrect context. If you add in "check selinux contexts, they may be wrong", I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Suggestion added.

Comment: It is new year, why you spending so much time on the server? LOL. HAPPY NEW YEAR!!